# New thread per each boolean true combination

Tags: java, concurrency, binary, boolean, combinations

I have a doubt about what would be the better way to achieve this:

I have a Class that contains 5 boolean variables (example: 11111, being one combination). Now, the thing is that I'm gonna start a new thread per each true combination, meaning that if i have 11000 i want to start a thread for 11000, another for 10000 and the last one for 01000.

I have to know all the values of the input combinations. The most obvious and inefficient way would be just comparing all the 32 (in this case) combinations (00000, 00001, etc.) and starting only when and AND of that and the actual value (11000) is != 0, that would be the cases that i previous mentioned (11000, 10000 and 01000).

In that case I'm gonna have to do 32 comparisons every single time. The thing is that if then i have 6 booleans now i have to do 64, and so on.

Anyone can think of a better strategy to "capture" every combination?

Comment: Since starting thread is quite an expensive operation it somewhat does not matter how complex code is to decide when to start new thread... But at this point it is quite unclear what exactly you have problem with - it seem you just need to start 31 thread corresponding to values 1-31 (skipping 00000)... Maybe [edit] the question to show code you have and brief explanation what part you measured already and found that it needs optimization.

Comment: Hi Alexei! I didn't code it yet, just seeing what would be the best (or at least good) approach. Im sorry but i don't need to start 31 threads, i just need to start a thread for each combination of true bits. The thing is that i have to test all 31 combinations that have a true bit, and thats for 5 bits. Maybe if then there are more bits the thing starts to get bigger. My question was if this was the only approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way to do it faster is through pre-calculation.

So, `String[][] arr;` and `for (String a : arr[5]) {/* thread creation etc */}` should be used.

Where '5' it is '00101'.

Also might helps: `Integer.toBinaryString(5)` and `(int) Long.parseLong("00101", 2)`.

Comment: Hi Timur! Im sorry but im only seeing 3 combinations (10010, 10000 and 00010). I only need one thread per each "true" combination of the input. The thing is that im putting this on binary to make it easier to explain, but those are 5 differents boolean, so i think that the order would be critical, it would be ok to ignore 0 for calculate the operations, but in the end i need to know all the bits states (10010, 10000 and 00010). Thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. At least on '1' should be for your case as I see now. So, you just should except this case like `a^b - 1`. Please, add to your question info that for each thread name strings like '10010' must be set. - it is not obvious.

Comment: Thing is that knowing how many comparisons i have to do its not the trouble, here. The thing is that i have to start each one of the thread for each combination but knowing the actual combination, the only way i came up is the one that i descrypted in the original post, (comparing all 31 values and doing the AND), that would be one way of doing it and its gonna work, but the question is if there is any other way (maybe that doesn't have to do (2^n)-1 comparisons being n booleans.

Comment: completely edited now